# Retrofit incorrect response error on android

Tags: android, web-services, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

When i call any webService with expired token,the service returns code 498 with error message "your tokken is expired"..BUT the retrofit gives the response code 500 with error message " internel server error".

```
response.code() //500  instead of 498
```

I tested the same url with postman and its working fine but the issue is only with retrofit.

I am using same services on IOS with AFNetworking and its also working fine there.

Any body can help to figure out why this is happening? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but it's too big for a comment.

5xx codes are server errors, this means that the server is crashing, not the app nor is retrofit buggy. The issue most likely is in the server, but can be caused by retrofit - yes, that's true.

My experience with all the questions that say: "I tried this *insert random network call here* with postman and it works, but retrofit returns 500" is because postman adds headers by default, which retrofit doesn't. The server implementation then expects these headers to be set and due to a faulty implementation crashes if said headers are missing.

I would check the headers retrofit is sending and the headers postman is sending and compare both and make sure which one crashes the server.

It can also be that `OkHttp` (Retrofit uses `OkHttp` under the hood) is adding some headers which the server cannot cope with. This would be stranger to me, but not impossible. I think it adds for example by default `gzip` and some servers might not handle this correctly.

If you have access to the server, than it might even be worth checking there the logs. They might point you right away to the issue.

I'm sorry but I cannot point you directly to the problem. These are just tips to get you started. Hope they help.